How to automatically close the dropdown list of an ActiveX ComboBox
I want the dropdown list of the ComboBox to close when I select another cell or switch to another sheet. For example, if I open the ComboBox in cell G8 and the dropdown list is shown, but I don't select anything from that list and then select cell A8, the cell A8 is selected but the dropdown list remains open and frozen. The same happens if I switch sheets; if the dropdown list is visible and I switch sheets, the dropdown list remains frozen in the middle of the screen, interfering with the new sheet.
How should I handle this?
This is my code:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Me.Range("G8:G407")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        With Me.ComboBox1
            .Visible = True
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Width = Target.Width
            .Height = Target.Height
            .LinkedCell = Target.Address
            .ListFillRange = "JURISDICCIONES!A2:A26"
            .DropDown
        End With
    End If
End Sub

I tried setting up the ComboBox so that its dropdown list would automatically close when selecting a different cell or switching to another sheet. I expected that when changing cells or sheets, the dropdown list would close as intended. However, the dropdown list remains open and visible, causing it to overlap and interfere with the new selection or sheet.

Are you using Excel as a database? This would be so much easier with Access. I am testing your code and see the issue. Review https://devcodef1.com/news/1359144/solving-dropdown-list-issue-in-activex-combobox

You don't show code for your attempts to close combobox dropdown. When you have issue implementing suggested code, post your code. Edit question or start a new one.

I was able to solve the problem by installing Microsoft Office 365. The ComboBox closes when I stop interacting with it, without the need for any code.

That will also not help. You need to solve it via code. I have Microsoft Office 365 and I am able to repro your issue. Let me know if you want a code solution.
